# Modify Kubernetes cluster criSocket setting

Tags: kubernetes, configuration

I have a Kubernetes lab environment for studying an online course. 
I missed a step in the installation instructions and didn't change the criSocket setting. 
How can I change this setting and keep the rest of the cluster configuration? 
I don't want to regenerate default cluster config, as I did in when I installed Kuberentes:

```
kubeadm config print init-defaults | tee ClusterConfiguration.yaml
```

The cluster contains 1 control plane node and 3 worker nodes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cri-socket` is a setting for kubelet.

If you have already done some specific settings for the CRI that you want to use, I guess you can switch to the other CRI by editing `/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`.

After stopping kubelet, add/modify `--container-runtime-endpoint=...` on that file and restart kubelet. Then kubelet will use a new CRI which is specified there.

This article may help you: https://dev.to/stack-labs/how-to-switch-container-runtime-in-a-kubernetes-cluster-1628

Comment: I found out that in version 1.20 that I installed, containerd is already the default.
So I didn't have to change from Docker to containerd https://kubernetes.io/blog/2020/12/02/dont-panic-kubernetes-and-docker/